# How to query a SQL Server backup file

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a backup file `B:\backups\full_backup.bak` but I do not know what backups this file has or what files each back has. How can I write a query to restore a database from this backup file?

I have tried to restore database but it threw an error saying

> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   File 'Application_Primary' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Application_Primary.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to
>   identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   File 'Application_FTS' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Application_FTS.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to
>   identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   File 'Application_Log' cannot be restored to 'L:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Application_Log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to
>   identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Code:

```
restore database Application_db
From disk = 'B:\backups\full_backup.bak'
```

Comment: Maybe use SQL Management Studio to restore it instead of sql commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to me that you are trying to restore a backup which has a database backup from another server with some path stored for data file (.mdf,ldf).

You will need to restore the database using the `MOVE` clause. Just the `RESTORE` command will try to restore database to the paths of the database from where this backup was taken.

**To Check what backups there are in a backup File**

```
USE master;
GO

RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = N'B:\backups\full_backup.bak'
GO
```

This will return the backups this backup file holds. You need to make sure what `Position` you backup file is at.

**To Check what files are in a backup File**

```
USE master;
GO

RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = N'B:\backups\full_backup.bak'
 WITH FILE = 1    --<-- Position of backup in the backup file 
GO
```

This will return the files that particular backup has. You will need these file names for `MOVE` clause in your restore statement.

**Restore Database**

```
USE master;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [Application_DB]
 FROM DISK = N'B:\backups\full_backup.bak'
WITH FILE = 1             --<-- position of database backup in the backup file 
,MOVE N'Application_Primary' TO N'D:\<some valid path>\Application_Primary.mdf'
,MOVE N'Application_FTS'     TO N'D:\<some valid path>\Application_FTS.ndf'
,MOVE N'Application_Logy'    TO N'D:\<some valid path>\Application_Log.ldf'
,RECOVERY;
```

GO

Comment: what if he want to store the info of the backup file or display the info from other application?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore `HEADERONLY` of the file to see exactly which backups it contains:

```
DECLARE @HeaderInfo table
  (
        BackupName  nvarchar(128),
        BackupDescription  nvarchar(255) ,
        BackupType  smallint ,
        ExpirationDate  datetime ,
        Compressed  bit ,
        Position  smallint ,
        DeviceType  tinyint ,
        UserName  nvarchar(128) ,
        ServerName  nvarchar(128) ,
        DatabaseName  nvarchar(128) ,
        DatabaseVersion  int ,
        DatabaseCreationDate  datetime ,
        BackupSize  numeric(20,0) ,
        FirstLSN  numeric(25,0) ,
        LastLSN  numeric(25,0) ,
        CheckpointLSN  numeric(25,0) ,
        DatabaseBackupLSN  numeric(25,0) ,
        BackupStartDate  datetime ,
        BackupFinishDate  datetime ,
        SortOrder  smallint ,
        CodePage  smallint ,
        UnicodeLocaleId  int ,
        UnicodeComparisonStyle  int ,
        CompatibilityLevel  tinyint ,
        SoftwareVendorId  int ,
        SoftwareVersionMajor  int ,
        SoftwareVersionMinor  int ,
        SoftwareVersionBuild  int ,
        MachineName  nvarchar(128) ,
        Flags  int ,
        BindingID  uniqueidentifier ,
        RecoveryForkID  uniqueidentifier ,
        Collation  nvarchar(128) ,
        FamilyGUID  uniqueidentifier ,
        HasBulkLoggedData  bit ,
        IsSnapshot  bit ,
        IsReadOnly  bit ,
        IsSingleUser  bit ,
        HasBackupChecksums  bit ,
        IsDamaged  bit ,
        BeginsLogChain  bit ,
        HasIncompleteMetaData  bit ,
        IsForceOffline  bit ,
        IsCopyOnly  bit ,
        FirstRecoveryForkID  uniqueidentifier ,
        ForkPointLSN  numeric(25,0) NULL,
        RecoveryModel  nvarchar(60) ,
        DifferentialBaseLSN  numeric(25,0) NULL,
        DifferentialBaseGUID  uniqueidentifier ,
        BackupTypeDescription  nvarchar(60) ,
        BackupSetGUID  uniqueidentifier NULL,
        CompressedBackupSize  numeric(20,0)
  )


 INSERT INTO @HeaderInfo EXEC('RESTORE HEADERONLY 
 FROM DISK = N''B:\backups\full_backup.bak''
 WITH NOUNLOAD')

 SELECT * FROM @HeaderInfo
```

is case of the error: MSSQLServer creates database phisical files in the path of main database file which has been backed up unless you specify a new path for the database files with `move` command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Application
   FROM DISK=N'B:\backups\full_backup.bak'
   WITH FILE 1,--use currect file number
   MOVE 'Application_Primary' TO 'C:\Application_Primary.mdf', 
   MOVE 'Application_FTS' TO 'C:\Application_FTS.mdf', 
   MOVE 'Application_Log' TO 'C:\Application_Log.ldf'
```

Comment: declaring this table variable and selecting from it, a bit of a overkill isnt it :)

Comment: maybe he would like to save the info of the backup file or display if from other application, also pay attention to with nounload